# How to achieve row-hover styling in vaadin-grid?

Tags: javascript, web-component, polymer-2.x, vaadin-grid

I am trying to achieve row-hover styling in vaadin-grid, where on hovering over a row, its style is changed.
My code is

```
<dom-module id="grid-styles" theme-for="vaadin-grid">
    <template>
        <style>
             [part~="body-cell"] :hover {
                 background-color: beige;
            }   
        </style>
    </template>
</dom-module>
```

But this code is not working. Can someone please help. Also there is no documentation on it.

PS. In previous versions this was done using `--vaadin-grid-body-row-hover-cell`.

EDIT: I have user the following code but it effects only the cells, not the row as a whole

```
[part~="cell"]:hover ::slotted(vaadin-grid-cell-content) {
  background-color: beige;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is how I did this (some styles have deeper, more specific selectors):

```html
<dom-module id="grid-styles" theme-for="vaadin-grid">
  <template>
      <style>
        :host [part~="row"]:hover [part~="body-cell"]{
          background-color: rgba(0, 55, 108, 0.12);
        } 

        :host [part~="body-cell"] ::slotted(vaadin-grid-cell-content){
          cursor: pointer;
        }
      </style>
  </template>
</dom-module>
```

Answer (score 2):

The following code does this

```
[part~="row"]:hover > [part~="body-cell"]{
background-color: beige;
}
```